# Android GPS on Marketplace

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

Hey all, I have an application on the marketplace that I have developed for my disseration project. The problem is that is uses a google map to display the users location and a map of the surroundings. It works in the debug but if I/anyone downloads the application from the marketplace the google map just has the grid with the lines on it and no satellite image of the map. The GPS is working as you can see the grid is moving.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Have you signed the apk? If you have , generate a new debug keystore and get a new map api key.